# Meta-alias in Git Bash

Tags: git, bash, alias

**Question**

I'm curious to know if one can create an alias for making aliases in Git, i.e. a meta-alias, so that instead of typing `git config --global alias.`-whatever one can just write `git alias`-whatever.

**Background:**

1. I'm just warming to Bash and Git, and have recently started creating aliases like `git cfg` for `git config --global` and, [from this page](http://githowto.com/aliases), `git hist` for:

   ```
   git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short
   ```
2. This last example is set by typing:

   ```
   git config --global alias.hist 'log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short'
   ```
3. With my `git cfg` alias I can shorten that to:

   ```
   git cfg alias.hist 'log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short'
   ```

But I'm trying to figure out if I can shorten it further still so that `git cfg alias.` is just `git alias`, partly out of convenience, partly out of curiosity, partly out of a desire to learn more about Git and Bash in general.

**Attempted solution?:**

1. I have found I can call `git $(echo 'cfg')` and get the same results as `git cfg`.
2. So I tried to create an alias for `alias` by entering this:

   ```
   git cfg alias.alias '$(echo "config --global alias.")'
   ```

   in the hope that I could type something like `git alias st status` to create a quick alias `git st` for `git status`.
3. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work because at this point Git no longer recognises `$(echo` as a command, even though it worked outside the context of the alias, as with `git $(echo 'cfg')`. I'm also not sure if something like this *would* work given that the `st` in the example would have to be appended directly to the `alias.` from the executed echo.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#alias):

```
Now that you know all about aliases, it might be handy to define some, using an alias:

    [alias]
            alias = "!sh -c '[ $# = 2 ] && git config --global alias.\"$1\" \"$2\" && exit 0 || echo \"usage: git alias <new alias> <original command>\" >&2 && exit 1' -"

then define new aliases with:

    $ git alias new_alias original_command
```

The expression `[ $# = 2 ]` is a shell expression that is true if the number of arguments equals two.

The structure looks like:

```
not <shell cmd> AND exit 0 OR <display syntax> AND exit 1
```

Which is shell language for, if the number of arguments is two, and git returns success, then return success (0).  Else, print a syntax error message, and return failure (1).

Comment: Not only does this work, but the explanation helps too :-) Thanks!